# hover on a element and display li elements

Tags: css

I have a problem with hovering on first li or a element to display rest li elements. It's working only if i set hover for ul, but then it's displaying li elements if i hover near the link, since it's block level element.

How can i make work hover on a elemet instead of ul

This is what i have now:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}

li:first-child a {
    display: block;
}

ul:hover a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set ul to inline-block so hover not triggered when you hover the line(row)

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

li:first-child a{
  display: inline-block;
}

li:hover ~ li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` to select all the siblings of the 1st list item. You can avoid the block level 100% problem, by floating the list items to the left (width of element is the content's width), and clearing the float to break the line.

```css
li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

li:first-child a {
  display: block;
}

li:first-child:hover~li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the problem is same, if you hover near link, rest li elements get displayed, so hover then must be used on a element to avoid this

Comment: Indeed. Do you need the bullets of the list items?